# Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'UIImage?' and 'String' - Swift 4

Tags: swift, string, uiimageview, uiimage

I'm making a car quiz app where the user will try to match the model with the brand(make). Both the models and brands are presented as UIImages.

```
let carModelList = ["Camaro",
                    "Mustang",
                    "Challenger"]

let carBrandList = ["Chevy",
                    "Ford",
                    "Dodge"]
```

I need to check to see if the user made a correct match. I'm doing it by comparing array indices...

```
if carModel.image == carModelList[0] && carBrand.image == carBrandList[0] {
```

In this example there would be a correct match because the Camaro is made by Chevy.

But, I get this error...

**Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'UIImage?' and 'String'**

So, I tried changing the array to ...

```
var carModelList: [UIImage] = [
    UIImage(named: "Camaro")!,
    UIImage(named: "Mustang")!,
    UIImage(named: "Challenger")!
]

var carBrandList: [UIImage] = [
    UIImage(named: "Chevy")!,
    UIImage(named: "Ford")!,
    UIImage(named: "Dodge")!
]
```

But, then at my two lines of code that randomly select the images to be presented to the user ...

```
carModel.image = UIImage(named: carModelList.randomElement()!)
carBrand.image = UIImage(named: carBrandList.randomElement()!)
```

I get this error ...

**Cannot convert value of type 'UIImage' to expected argument type 'String'**

Comment: Thats because you use same names for image array and string array

Comment: you can't compare image with string , you need to compare the selected  image string with whatever other string

Comment: another tip if you need help don't act deaf , you should be curious to ask and try in real time

Comment: Why don't you store in arrays both the name and the UIImage, as t-uple ? let carModelList = [("Camaro", UIImage(named: "Camaro")!), etc… ] Doing so, you could easily compare if carModel.image == carModelList[0].1  or in the second setting carModel.image = UIImage(named: carModelList.randomElement()!.0)

Comment: What type is carModel?

Comment: Sh_Khan ... Perhaps you are being insensitive to deaf people. I simply had to step away from my computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're being presented with that message because indeed you're trying to pass an image, but the constructor is expecting the name of the image, which is a String.

if you wanna call it like this:

```
carModel.image = UIImage(named: carModelList.randomElement()!)
carBrand.image = UIImage(named: carBrandList.randomElement()!)
```

Your array has to look like this :

```
var carModelList: [String] = [
    "Camaro",
    "Mustang",
    "Challenger"
]

var carBrandList: [String] = [
    "Chevy",
    "Ford",
    "Dodge"
]
```

The other option is to call it like this by using your array of images:

```
carModel.image = carModelList.randomElement()!
carBrand.image = carBrandList.randomElement()!
```

Make sure to avoid force unwrapping.

Also, your String arrays and UIImage arrays have the same same, rename them if you wanna compare them.

Comment: Thank you. This is the correct answer. Just as a note, I did not use the String array and UIImage arrays together. I was trying each out separately.

Comment: Mr. Vollbrecht ... I believe that it will be safe to force unwrap in my case because, in this app, I will always have arrays with hard-coded objects in them. I will also always have corresponding images for those objects in my Assets file.

Comment: if that is the case, then no problem!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you use

```
let carModelList = ["Camaro",
                "Mustang",
                "Challenger"]

 let carBrandList = ["Chevy",
                "Ford",
                "Dodge"]
```

AND

```
var carModelList: [UIImage] = [
    UIImage(named: "Camaro")!,
    UIImage(named: "Mustang")!,
    UIImage(named: "Challenger")!
]

var carBrandList: [UIImage] = [
    UIImage(named: "Chevy")!,
    UIImage(named: "Ford")!,
    UIImage(named: "Dodge")!
]
```

With same array names, that why when you do == swift can't understand which one you are using

Comment: I don't use them at the same time. I was trying each of them out separately.

Comment: @sdca just try to rename it